# html2pdf generates corrupted parts in the downloaded file

Tags: html, angularjs, amcharts, html2pdf

I used html2pdf in my code to enable converting html files to pdf ones then downloading them.
In my html file I have some statistic graphics coded using amChart.
The problem is that I have got a perfect file but with corrupted parts. The parts that contains the amChart graphics.Here is the graph in the html page:[image]
and here is what I have got in the downloaded pdf file[image]
 I used this code to enable the download (with angular I just installed the necessary dependecies using bower).
    Hello Someone

```
<div pdf-save-content="idOne" >
    Hello Someone
</div>
```

Can someone please help me fix this problem?
I know that amchart  provides a library to download the graphs with different forms (csv, png,pdf,..) it's not what need, I need to download the whole page.
it's not either a width problem.

Comment: can you try 'htmlto' npm module to convert html to pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this problem I used this amCharts [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/35076c4d7b6eef7764dacc61f72adadc). It was better to use pdfMake than html2pdf

```
chart["export"].toPDF(layout, function(data) {
  this.download(data, "application/pdf", "amCharts.pdf");
});
```